# Can I use multiple displays on a MacBook Pro using a TV connected by Thunderbolt/HDMI?

Tags: display, hdmi, dual-screen

With a MacBook Pro, can I  watch a film on the TV connected externally to HDMI while browsing the web on the MacBook screen?

Comment: Does anyone know of a tutorial for this? I have just switched from PC to Mac so am new to all of this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you can control what plays on multiple displays by dragging windows across the combined desktop or using Mission Control to direct a video player to the external connection while keeping your other windows on the internal display.